# How to auto configure local domain to point at docker container

Tags: macos, docker, dns, development-environment, host

My aim is to have a self-contained repository that a user/developer can pull down (on a mac), type `docker-compose up -d` and have a working development environment via a friendly url like `http://myproject.dev/`

I have my docker images set up as needed but the local domain is where i've come unstuck. I know this is a bit outside of Docker, as this is a host system thing. But i'm really looking for a way to achieve this without requiring the user to install local apps or make various local system config changes.

Is this something that is achievable, or am i barking up the wrong tree?

**Sorry guys, i missed out some important info. I ideally want to avoid pointing to localhost as this would cause conflicts if/when running multiple projects. So i guess we would need to point to the containers IP, so host entries would need to be dynamic. murky dns waters indeed

Comment: This won't be possible without some configuration on the host machine (at the very least, adding an entry for `/etc/resolver/dev`. Are the resolvers for the machines all the same where you could do it at the upstream DNS?

Comment: Unfortunately not, is it possible to run a script when launching Docker to perform the local changes?

Comment: Also, i have concerns about conflicts if we run multiple projects at the same time. In that case pointing to localhost is not an option, and we need a way to point at the containers IP dynamically right?

Comment: You generally can't connect directly to Docker containers from the hosts without some additional configuration anyways. The Docker NAT handles the port forwarding from the host to the containers. It sounds like what you really might be looking for is some management layer over Docker that handles creation of these services, static IP address -> NAT mapping per service, and the creation of DNS records. Unfortunately, I don't know if something like this exists at the moment (i'm thinking something like pow.cx or Anvil for Docker).

Answer (score 1):

I know you said:

> ... or make various local system config changes.

But if you can lift that requirement, the one change you need to make for local macOS systems would be an addition to `/etc/resolver/dev`. Then, you can run a DNS server to your `docker-compose.yml` that automatically adds entries for the services such as https://github.com/ruudud/devdns (specifically, the https://github.com/ruudud/devdns#host-machine--containers bit).

Comment: I think you are right, its not really going to work without adding a local host entry. Is there anyway you know of to run a script pre `up` to add this without creating an extra step for users?

Answer (score 0):

Point a real world [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) record that all your developers can lookup to 127.0.0.1. So `myproject.existing.tld` would point to `127.0.0.1`.

An example is vmware's [could application platform](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-attic/vcap):

```
→ dig +noall +answer vcap.me
vcap.me.        3412    IN  A   127.0.0.1
→ dig +noall +answer whatever.vcap.me
vcap.me.        3412    IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

Otherwise your treading into the murky waters of advertising services via
[mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) (or [LLMNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution)) and [Zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking).

Comment: murky waters indeed! localhost isnt ideal due to conflicts (very sorry my question want very helpful on this point), so i guess that leaves me with dns work

Comment: I use common private network alias addresses on client machines to work around the conflict issue. So I expect any 10.8.0.0/16 addresses to potentially be locally hosted, or if not local then routed to a host on the local network that hosts the service.

Comment: ...but that also takes local setup to persist each ip on an interface.